# List Samba users?

Tags: user-accounts, samba

So yesterday evening I was pulling my hair out (figuratively -- I'm bald) for over an hour trying to figure out why `smbpasswd` kept rejecting my attempts to reset the password for one of my Samba users. Anyway, long story short, it was apparently because the user didn't exist yet (`smbpasswd -a` added her without complaint, and now everything's hunky-dory), even though I still swear up and down that I did indeed add her already.

Anyway, if I could have simply listed the users in the smbpasswd database, it would saved me a lot of grief. Is there a command or utility that can do that? (Samba's using that new-fangled .tdb database, otherwise I would have just `cat /etc/smbpasswd`.)

Answer (score 280, accepted):

I believe the command your looking for is `pdbedit`.

From the [man](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/pdbedit.8.html) page "pdbedit - manage the SAM database (Database of Samba Users)"

```
sudo pdbedit -L -v
```

`-L` to list users. `-v` to be verbose.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I get `tdbsam_open: Failed to open/create TDB passwd [/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb]`

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I get this error, too, when I run that command WITHOUT sudo! running it with sudo works fine

Answer (score 17):

In Samba 4 and later, if yours is an AD server, there's also [`samba-tool user list`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/samba-tool.8.html#idm1034) and other useful user management commands.

For Workgroup or NT4 domain Samba servers, `pbdedit -L -v` as above.

Comment: I believe this is only if you set up Samba to be an AD server. With a workgroup or NT4 domain Samba server, you need `pdbedit -L` as in the accepted answer.

Comment: `samba-tool` also doesn’t seem to be available from standard RHEL/CentOS RPM repositories: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=6368