# How to list active samba users?

Tags: user-accounts, samba

I could not find a pdbedit or smbldap-userlist option to list just the active samba users.

Solution on Question [1] lists all users and machines and smbldap-userlist -ua lists all users, even if they are inactive. I mean Inactive, not a logged off user but a user that is not active on the domain anymore.

I tried awk and grep to parse the output but I could not match a pattern on [status SMB] column.

Does somebody has a command-line or shell solution?
(although, a Python solution will be very welcome)

[1] [List Samba users?](https://superuser.com/questions/271034/list-samba-users)

Comment: What do you mean with a user that is not active on the domain? Do you mean that you would like to hide accounts that are disabled?

Answer (score 4):

The "smbstatus" tool should show the currently active users on a server. There might be some false positives as workstations often keep connections open after a user has logged off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I didn't explain the problem well. I want the users that CAN login, not the users logged on a certain time. I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following simple bash script. It rules out machine accounts and disabled accounts (account flags W and D)

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd ~
lista=`pdbedit -L | sort | uniq | cut -f1 --delimiter=':'`

for i in $lista
do
        ret=`pdbedit -L -v $i | grep "Account Flags" | cut -f2 --delimiter='[' | cut -f1 --delimiter=' '`
        ismachine_account=`echo $ret | grep W | wc -l`
        isdeleted_account=`echo $ret | grep D | wc -l`
        if [ $ismachine_account -eq 0 -a $isdeleted_account -eq 0 ]; then
                echo $i
        fi
done    
exit
```