# How to see if a network share is used?

Tags: linux, opensuse, nfs, smb

In my network there are Windows and openSUSE machines. The openSUSE boxes are using Samba shares to show their data to the Windows ones and they are using NFS to share data among themselves.

Now I want to reboot one of the openSUSE PCs. How can I see, if a user currently is working on the affected file system through SMB or NFS?

Comment: Does this helps (for the Samba users): http://superuser.com/questions/271034/list-samba-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the smbstatus command for samba. 
Maybe lsof can help for NFS, not sure.